# Text align to absolute bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to push the text I have in my header so that the bottom of each character touches the bottom of the div. Almost as if the border for the div underlined each letter. How would I accomplish this? Im basically trying to push the text I have down a couple pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to set the container's position to relative, and the child element to absolute:

```
<div style="position:relative;height:200px;border:1px solid #ccc;">
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;">
        I'm a bottom feeder...
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Just for clarification, I am not using `line-height` because it does not behave correctly if the text wraps to a new line.

See here for a breakdown of the different techniques. Particularly note the examples using relative vs. absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2tqZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/g835a/4/

style.css

```
.header
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#header-content { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

html:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="header-content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1: Of the two ways that this can be done, this is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" you are encountering is caused by the font.  Fonts, generally, leave room under letters to account for descenders like "j" and "g".  You will need to adjust the negative value of the bottom attribute accordingly.

change the bottom value from 0 to -5 in magnum2002's fiddle and it works.

Answer (score -1):

CSS:

```
 text{
    vertical-align:baseline;
  }
```

Something like that?